# jQuery.ajax Variable Data Object Key

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do something similar to the following problem: [ASP.NET: jQuery AJAX 'data' param problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061884/asp-net-jquery-ajax-data-param-problem).

My code looks like this:

```
var key = jQuery(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
var value = 1;

var object = {};
object[key]=value;

jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "",    
                data: object
            }).done(function() {
                alert("message");
            });
```

This does nothing at all. I know this should be simple, but I'm not getting anything. Still very new to jQuery and Javascript/AJAX. I have narrowed the problem down to the data object.

For example, if I do it this way

```
data: {1:1}
data: {2:1}
data: {3:1} etc.
```

it works, but I need my key value to be variable based on the ID of the element referenced, as opposed to constant.

To summarize, I am looking for a way to have a variable key in the AJAX key/value pairs.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In data section write: {key+':'+value}. Again, your url can not be empty, set your dataType too, like : dataType:json

Comment: Hmm. Using data: {key+':'+value}, crashes the script. I tried setting the dataType. No change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the `key` you're getting is not null or empty before using it.

Then to populate the object you could try

```
    var theKey = jQuery(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
    var theValue = 1;
    var dict = []; // create an empty array
    dict.push({ key: theKey, value: theValue });
```

Then try handling the `success` and `error` methods instead.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Your Url here',
    data: dict,
    success: function () {
        alert("message");
    },
    error: function (req, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Key is not null. Just checked. Using the code you suggested, I'm seeing no errors.