# jquery ajax code won't fire the code behind

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, code-behind

first, sorry for my bad English.... I've created an example page for testing jquery ajax. but I cant. I've created a db and 2 txtbox on the page and a html button. I want the textbox values save to db when button is pressed. here is my script:

```
$(function () {
    $('#Button1').click(function () {
        var udata = new Object();
        udata.name = $('#Text1').val();
        udata.fam = $('#Text2').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "default.aspx/InsertData",
            data: udata,
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () { alert("ok"); },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

and my code behind is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.Services;
namespace ajax_example
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        [WebMethod]
        protected static void InsertData(string name,string fam)
        {
            //some code
        }
    }
```

}
and when I press the button, I always get the error message. please help me .what is wrong with this?!

Comment: You're not passing the correct number of parameters that your method requires.

Comment: tow parameters for each.  I don't understand

Comment: pass data in the same way this has been done and not as an object like you do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061884/asp-net-jquery-ajax-data-param-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code behind  web method must be public not protected.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it:

Try passing the data as a string, not an object. The reason for this is that if you specify an object as data then jQuery serializes the data using query string format, whereas the server is expecting JSON format directly.
Jquery-

```
   $('#Button1').click(function () {
            var name = "ssd"; //$('#Text1').val();
            var fam = "dfss"; //$('#Text2').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "testjob.aspx/InsertData",
                data: '{name: ' + "'" + name + "'" + ',fam: ' + "'" + fam + "'" + '}',
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) { alert("ok"); },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

C# Code - make webmethod `public`

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
 public static void InsertData(string name, string fam)
  {
      //some code
  }
```